# How to properly return a unique_ptr from a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Let the code explain by itself:

```
class SomeClass {
private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyType>> cache;
public:
  std::unique_ptr<MyType> getAt1(int i);
  MyType* getAt2(int i);
}
```

```
std::unique_ptr<MyType> SomeClass::getAt1(int i) {
  return std::move(cache[i]);
}
MyType* SomeClass::getAt2(int i) {
  return cache[i].get();
}
```

I'm wondering if getAt1 will make my vector inconsistent, or both ways are ok.
Due to architecture flaws, I really should return as getAt1 does.

What's your opinion?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends what you want. Do you want to remove the pointer from the vector? Or do you want a pointer that points to the same object as the pointer in the vector? Will the vector always outlive the pointer you return from the function?

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
return std::move(cache[i]);
```

modifies the smart pointer inside the vector. It is no longer managing a `MyType` pointer. `get()` will return `nullptr` afterwards. I don't think that's what you want.

If you want to grant access to the instance for short-term use, just return a reference to the managed object:

```
MyType& SomeClass::getAt1(int i)
{
    return *cache[i];
}
```

The usual caveats apply here. The reference might become invalid if the `unique_ptr` in `cache` is changed (destroyed, reassigned, reset, etc.) A returned reference is only for short-term use.

This of course assumes the `unique_ptr` is never a `nullptr`. It's not clear whether or not you allow `nullptr` values in `cache`. If yes, then don't return a reference. Return a raw pointer instead, as per your `getAt2()` example. The same caveats still apply. The returned pointer will become invalid if the `unique_ptr` changes.

Finally, all this assumes that `SomeClass` is the owner of the `MyType` objects in `cache`, and the `get()` function only grants temporary, non-owning access to the objects. If not, then you should switch to `shared_ptr` instead and also return a `shared_ptr`:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyType> SomeClass::getAt1(int i)
{
    return cache[i];
}
```

Comment: 1. It's definitely going to be nullptr. The move constructor modifies the rhs.

2. A reference is fine, but it's undefined behavior if the pointer is null, so we have to be careful here.

Answer (score 1):

As you might already be aware, you could use shared_ptr instead of unique_ptr.

Comment: I would suggest that shared_ptr is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `getAt1` is that the element in the vector is then empty. I think you want to do `getAt2`, instead.